# Index exceeds the number of array elements (5)

Tags: matlab

The following is ok, but I want to multiply VR with coefficient 1.045, like M=1.045.*VR>Vs30 then it gives me an error of exceeding array elements. Besides this, I want to give lambda values at the same time as (36 38 40 42), for the individual value its fine like as given below its 36 it works abut when I add 38, 40 and 42 then it's not working.

```
R = [0.5:0.1:2.25];
    Vs1= [120];
    Vs2 = R.*Vs1;
    H1=[5:5:25];
    rho = [2000 2000];
    lambda = [36];

    for j=1:length(Vs2),
        Vs = [Vs1 Vs2(j)];
        for i=1:length(H1)
            H2=30-H1(i);
            d=[H1(i),H2];
            Vs30(j,i)=Vs30_fun(d,Vs);
            
        end
    end
    
    
    for j=1:length(Vs2),
        Vs = [Vs1 Vs2(j)];Vp=2.*Vs;
        for i=1:length(H1)
            d=[H1(i) Inf];
            VR(j,i)=lv_fun(d,Vs,Vp,rho,lambda);
            
        end
    end
    
    M=VR<Vs30;
    [m,n]=size(M);
    VR=zeros(length(Vs2),length(H1));
    for i=1:m
        for j=1:n        
            if M(i,j)==0
                plot(H1(i),R(j), 'r*')
                hold on
    %                drawnow();
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: What do the `Vs30_fun` and `lv_fun` functions return? a scalar value? An array?

Comment: Have you considered to set a breakpoint at the line where the error is thrown and to inspect your variables/arrays in workspace?